# Is there a correct way to load a script once, and use it in iFrames throughout the document?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, optimization, iframe

I have a web app that loads *widgets* to the dom via an `iframe`. These *widgets* are full HTML documents themselves and include `head`, `body`, and `script` tags. These *widgets* often load the same `scripts` (e.g. [Plotly.js](https://plot.ly/javascript/)), and have the (extra?) overhead of loading and parsing the script each time.

I am investigating to see if there is anything *smart* we can do with these duplicate dependencies - ideally load once only.

[image]

I had the idea of loading the `script` once (in the `parent`) and referencing it in the `iframes`. Something like this at the top of each *widget*:

```html
<script>
var Plotly = window.parent.Plotly;
</script>
```

This largely did not work (controls in strange places, no animations, not interactive): 
[image]

I am wondering is there a guaranteed-to-work way of achieving what I want to achieve? How can a `parent` properly inject a script into an `iframe`?

Prototypes here: [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/mi6Rl0ED4hbTVnkN6AjZ/) / [Web](https://pensive-wing-b83b27.netlify.com/)

Suggestions welcome.

Comment: You can reference the highest window in the hierarchy with `top`. Keep in mind the same-origin-policy.

Comment: Will this not result in the same value as `window.parent` (in this case, i.e. only one `<iframe>` deep?

Comment: In the main window, you should assign the property to the window object